# How should I POST to LinkedIn Invitation API with JSON?

Tags: python, json, post, linkedin-api

I am relatively new to Python (and code in general!) but I have successfully used LinkedIn's People Search API to obtain specific details of some of my second connections.

I am now trying to understand how to invite these connections through the Invitation API but am struggling. The documentation is [here](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/invitation-api).

I have obtained the necessary details such as "name" and "value" from the People Search, but now can't figure out how to POST using json and urllib2. Here's where I've gotten to, which is returning an HTTP Error 400: Bad Request.

I'm sure I'm missing something completely obvious - such is the joy of self-learning from scratch...

```
import json
import urllib2

opener = urllib2.build_opener()

data = json.dumps({"recipients": {"values": [{"person": {"_path": "/people/" + id}}]},"subject": "Invitation to connect.","body": "add me","item-content":{"invitation-request":{"connect-type":"friend", "authorization":{"name": "x-li-auth-token", "value": "abc1"}}}})
req = urllib2.Request('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/mailbox?format=json&oauth2_access_token=' + access_token, data, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
response = f.read()
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd give urllib2 a great big miss and move straight on to [Requests](http://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) (the documentation is [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html)).  I guarantee you will not regret it; I think that after the imports you'd be able to halve the lines of code.

I switched recently and haven't looked back, there's just too much not to like about a module that makes it all obvious and includes native JSON support.  The only reason I'm not including a working code snippet is I haven't played with the LinkedIn API at all.  So the only Requests code I've written is for looking up URL forwards, accessing an SMS gateway and accessing another HTTP-Post API.  Someone else has already written Twitter code using it.

Anyway, without a real code example, with Requests you would be getting rid of the opener line, changing the data format to something [like this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls), changing the req line to match the previous documentation for the API URL (e.g. r = requests.get()) and there would no longer be a need to open the response as a file and read it because r.text, r.json and r.content would be available.